# Plotting categorical data into a single bar plot of relative frequency with python/pandas/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I have a bunch of categorical data from a survey and I would like to plot it in the same way as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGidY.png). Effectively it is a bar shaped pie chart.

The data is in a pandas data frame, and here is a toy example of what I've tried to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# create toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Steve','Steve','Steve','Jon','Michael','Michael','Eric'] })


# get pd.Series of counts of each name
data_counts = df['Names'].value_counts()


# return the name of each category, and its counts separately
category_names = data_counts.index
category_counts = data_counts.get_values()


# attempt to plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
i=0
for name, data in zip(category_names, category_counts):

    sns.barplot(x=data, label=name, color=colors[i])
    i+=1

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size':12})
```

This produces a kind of stacked histogram, but each category is not proportionally represented. Each bar is over-plotted rather than plotted as a fractional share.

Is this along the right lines?

Comment: You know you're expected to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), right? This will help others who have a similar question in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't know there was a time limit on "accepting an answer". Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You have actually upvoted the answers, not accepted them :) You can upvote any good answer, but you can only accept one answer. You should accept the answer that worked best for you (which can be subjective). Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not using subplots properly, see here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Second, it is possible to plot a stacked bar chart with pandas' basic plotting functionality:

```
pd.DataFrame(data_counts).transpose().plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

Note that for the bars to be stacked, you have to transpose your data, and in order to transpose a pandas Series you need to convert it to a dataframe first.

[image: stacked_bars]

Finally, if you absolutely want to use Seaborn, this link might help: http://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/

Answer (score 1):

not the most elegant, but this will work:

```
x = df.Names.value_counts()
y = x.reset_index()
y["name_of_column"] = ""
y.pivot(index="name_of_column", columns="index", values=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```